# preg_replace how surround html attributes for a string with " in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

I have a string variable in PHP , its content is:

```
$var='<SPAN id=1 value=1 name=1> one</SPAN>
<div id=2 value=2 name=2> two</div >';
 ....
```

I need a function for surround html  attributes  with "" i need do this for the all  meta-tag

,etc the result should be this:

```
$var='<SPAN id= "1" value="1" name="1"> one </SPAN>
<div id="2" value="2" name="2" > two</div >';
 ...
```

I need replace all =[a-z][A-Z][1-9] for ="[a-z][A-Z][1-9]". I need a regular expresion for preg_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its is [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325320/php-use-preg-replace-for-replacing-word-with-double-quotes/13325389#13325389)

```
$var = preg_replace('/(?<==)(\b\w+\b)(?!")(?=[^<]*>)/', '"$1"', $var);
```

thanks for Ωmega, its works on IE8

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it all in single quotes like this:

```
$myHtml='<SPAN id="1" value="1" name="1"> one </SPAN>
    <div id="2" value="2" name="2" > two</div >';
```

Comment: thanks but I havent initially double quotes and it not appear for wrap it all in single quotes.

Comment: Okay, so your question is "How do I automatically add double quotes for these attributes?"

Comment: Note to down voter - check the pre-edit question to see why I have given this answer!

Answer (score 0):

use a [heredoc](http://php.net/heredoc) which removes the need to escape most anything except `$`:

```
$var = <<<EOL
<span id="1" value="1" name="1">one</span>
etc...
EOL
```

Comment: thanks but I havent initially double quotes to escape them.
Replacement is the problem. I have this =text and I need ="text"

Answer (score 0):

I would run the string through [`DOMDocument`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$var='<SPAN id=1 value=1 name=1> one</SPAN>
<div id=2 value=2 name=2> two</div >';

// Create a new DOMDocument and load your markup.
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($var);

// DOMDocument adds doctype and <html> and <body> tags if they aren't
// present, so find the contents of the <body> tag (which should be
// your original markup) and dump them back to a string.
$var = $dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0));

// Strip the actual <body> tags DOMDocument appended.
$var = preg_replace('#^<body>\s*(.+?)\s*</body>$#ms', '$1', $var);

// Here $var will be your desired output:
var_dump($var);
```

Output:

```
string(85) "<span id="1" value="1" name="1"> one</span>\n<div id="2" value="2" name="2"> two</div>"
```

Please note that if `$var` has the potential to contain an actual `<body>` tag, that modifications will need to be made to this code.  I leave that as an exercise to the OP.

Comment: its a good solution but i need this for IE8 and IE8's DOM dont surround atributes of metatag with "". IE8 do this <SPAN id=1 value=1 name=1> one</SPAN>. It is the problem because I need this solution.

Comment: This solution surrounds attributes with `"` characters, as I showed with the output.