# PHP Use preg_replace for replacing word with Double quotes

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [preg_replace how surround html attributes for a string with " in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323723/preg-replace-how-surround-html-attributes-for-a-string-with-in-php)

How to use `preg_replace()` for change all word that is within `<` `>` and after `=` for word  with double quote surround

```
$var="<myfootball figure=thin new=aux(comment); > this=Association football < name=football >"
```

to

```
$var="<myfootball figure="thin"  new="aux(comment);" >this=Association footballl<  name="football"  >"
```

What is the regular expresion for do this with `preg_replace()`?

Comment: yes this doubled because I had to reformulated my question because in the other thread  It didnt take a good course but I've closed the previous.

Comment: I did not put this possibility  new="aux"(aux); in my example. I now change my example.Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `(?<==)(\b\w+\b)(?!")(?=[^<]*>)` with `"$1"`

```
$var = preg_replace('/(?<==)(\b\w+\b)(?!")(?=[^<]*>)/', '"$1"', $var);
```

---

**EDIT** (based on OP's comment and question update) >>

Replace `(?<==)(\b\S+?)(?=[\s>])(?!")(?=[^<]*>)` with `"$1"`

```
$var = preg_replace('/(?<==)(\b\S+?)(?=[\s>])(?!")(?=[^<]*>)/', '"$1"', $var);
```

Comment: its good but if i Have  new=aux(aux); it not rules. the result  is new="aux"(aux);  I did not put this possibility in my example. I now change my example.Can you change the response to the new change? please

Comment: @Martin - Answer has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to put this in 2 regular expressions. The first expressions matches everything between `<` and `>` and the second expression quotes the text after `=`.

```php
 $value = preg_replace_callback('|<(.*?)>|', function($matches) {
      // $matches[1] is now the text between < and >
      return '<'.preg_replace('|=(\w+)|', '="\\1"', $matches[1]).'>';
 }, $var);
```